# Why does this work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, scope

Just now,I saw some code like this:

---

```
if(condition){
    var xx='sss';   
}
//do something

if(condition){
    console.info(xx);
}
```

---

Now, I just wonder why the second `if` statement work? How can it access the `xx` variable since it is a local variable defined in another `if` statement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`var` in JavaScript is scoped to the containing execution context (e.g., the whole function's scope, or the whole global scope if the `var` is at global scope), **not** the block. JavaScript doesn't (yet) have block scope (ECMAScript6 looks likely to add it, via the new `let` keyword).

The code you've quoted is **exactly** equivalent to this:

```
var xx;   
if(condition){
    xx='sss';   
}
//do something

if(condition){
    console.info(xx);
}
```

This is covered by [Section 10.5](http://es5.github.com/#x10.5) of the specification, which describes what the engine does when entering a new execution context. (It's basically a two-phase process, first setting up all the declarations, and then executing step-by-step code.)

More: [*Poor misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript the scope is exacted to the closure (the last enclosing function block, or defaults to the window object). When a variable is declared anywhere within that function block it is **hoisted** to the top of the scope, so in essence a variable exists as undefined starting at the very top of the scope if it is declared *anywhere* in the scope.

Think of it like this, when the code begins executing it scans all the instructions for declarations and allocates the symbol name starting immediately.

```
console.log(x);  // undefined
console.log(y);  // error: Uncaught ReferenceError: y is not defined
var x;
```

for that matter you can take it to extremes:

```
console.log(x);  // undefined, not an error

while (false) {
  if (false) {
    var x;
  }
}
```

even though `var x` can't possibly be reached, and during execution would be optimized away completely. the engine will still **hoist** the variable to the top of the scope

hope this helps -ck

useful link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taaEzHI9xyY&feature=youtu.be#t=42m57s

Comment: s/closure/function scope, if any, or top-level scope/. There is no closure in the above example.

Comment: so it defaults to the window object scope, the "global" scope, which if you want to think in terms of closures it is the entry point, eg, something (native code) has to "call" into your JavaScript entry point (the beginning of the file/script block)

Comment: +1 for extreme example of variable declaration that won't be reached but will still be parsed

Answer (score 1):

`var` declarations affect the entire scope of the smallest containing function or program.  JavaScript is not block scoped.

[Crock](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) says:

> **Variable Declarations**
>
> All variables should be declared before used. JavaScript does not require this, but doing so makes the program easier to read and makes it easier to detect undeclared variables that may become implied globals. Implied global variables should never be used.
>
> The `var` statements should be the first statements in the function body.
>
> It is preferred that each variable be given its own line and comment. They should be listed in alphabetical order.
>
> ```
> var currentEntry; // currently selected table entry
> var level;        // indentation level
> var size;         // size of table
> ```
>
> JavaScript does not have block scope, so defining variables in blocks can confuse programmers who are experienced with other C family languages. Define all variables at the top of the function.
>
> Use of global variables should be minimized. Implied global variables should never be used.

Note, this is changing with the [`let` statement](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:block_scoped_bindings), and in current JavaScript (EcmaScript 5), the variable name in a `catch` block is block scoped.

Answer (score 1):

javascript doesn't have block scope, so `var xx='sss'` is either locally scoped (if your sample code is inside a function) or globally scoped (if your sample code is not contained in a function).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a dynamic language, that isn't always picky about things like variable scoping.  So, this "feature" allows you to write the code

```
if (condition) {
    var xx = 'sss';
} else {
    var xx = 'ttt';
}

// do something

if (condition) {
    console.info(xx);
}
```

I would recommend avoiding this, since it makes your program harder to understanda and reason about.

Comment: This isn't strictly true. There is a different with and without `var` inside a function. (Or with strict mode.)

Comment: @pst Correct.  "isn't **always** picky"

Comment: You may it sound like a free-for-all. JavaScript's rules for `var` are very clearly defined by the specification, and are rigorously applied in all situations (so it's "always" consistent with the spec).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I agree with your overall point, but the definition of `var` has changed between EcmaScript 3 and EcmaScript 5 so I believe different versions of the spec say that `(function () { use strict; eval('var x;'); x = 1; })(); alert(typeof x);` and `(function () { var e = eval; e('var x;'); x = 1; })(); alert(typeof x);` are two programs that behave differently because of how `var` is speced, and some EcmaScript 3 implementations were non-compliant due to GC optimizations when running `f = (function() { var x=1; return function (a, b) { a(b); } })(); f(eval, 'x');`.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a variable using var within a function, the variable is scoped to within that function. An if statement is not a function.

I'm assuming in this case both if statements are within the same function and therefore xx is in scope?

Answer (score -1):

If a variable is declared inside a conditional statement, it is still available anywhere following the declaration in the containing function (or globally if the conditional is not in a function). However, it will equal undefined if the condition evaluates to false, unless the variable is later assigned a value.

If a local variable is referenced globally or in another function, a JavaScript error will occur. Depending on your browser, the error may say the variable "is not defined" or "is undefined". This is different from the variable equaling undefined like mentioned above, because a variable that equals undefined can still be referenced.

Comment: -1: Your first sentence is false. If a variable is declared inside a conditional statement, the variable is available everywhere in the function (or global scope). To take it to an extreme, you can always declare your variables at the bottom of your functions and they will still be hoisted up to the top.