# Variable is undefined in local scope if declared in upper scope and a var with same name is declared in local scope in an unexecuted statement

Tags: javascript

```
function a(){
    var h = 1;
    function b(){
        alert(h);
    }
    b();
}
a();
```

alerts **1**;

```
function a(){
    var h = 1;
    function b(){
        if(false){
            var h = h * 2;
        }
        alert(h);
    }
    b();
}
a();
```

alerts **undefined**. Why ?

Comment: Because you declare the var h two times

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630373/will-i-have-any-problems-if-i-declare-the-same-variable-multiple-times

Comment: Is `if(false)` meant to do something?

Comment: JS doesn't have block level scope and variables are hoisted.  Might consider reading up on hoisting if you are unfamiliar

Comment: The keyword here is "hoisting". See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/9389454/218196

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Hoisted' JavaScript Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667199/hoisted-javascript-variables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables in function scope are in scope throughout the entire function. It doesn't matter that the `var` is inside a block. So this:

```
function b(){
    if(false){
        var h = h * 2;
    }
    alert(h);
}
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
function b(){
    var h;
    if(false){
        h = h * 2;
    }
    alert(h);
}
```

It doesn't matter that the surrounding function also has a variable named `h`.

Comment: As you posted at the same time of thefourtheye, but you gave the hint about the fact that a.h doesn't matter in b scope in this case, I accepted yours

Answer (score 5):

Variable declarations are moved to the top of the scope they are defined in and the values are not assigned, till the assignment line is executed. So, your second code can be understood as

```
function a() {
    var h = 1;

    function b() {
        var h;
        if (false) {
            h = h * 2;
        }
        alert(h);
    }
    b();
}
a();
```

Even though you have defined `h` within the `if` clause, since JavaScript doesn't have block scoping, the variable declaration is actually moved to the top of the function. And since the `if` condition is not satisfied, `h` is never assigned a value. That is why it alerts `undefined`

Answer (score -1):

You are re declaring 'h' using 'var.'  remove the second instance of 'var.'  like this:

```
function a(){
    var h = 1;
    function b(){
        if(false){
            h = h * 2;
        }
        alert(h);
    }
    b();
}
a();
```

Comment: I think you may have missed the point of the question.  This code was specifically crafted to display a certain behavior and the OP would like to know why it works this way, not how to "fix" it.

Comment: this is not the same behavior as this will set the h of the a's scope

Comment: the "solution" to the problem would be to declare another variable with h's value into b's scope, and applying the * 2 on it, but as stated by @JamesMontagne, this isn't the purpose of the question

Comment: Right, I misunderstood.