# how does variable use before its declaration?

Tags: javascript, variables, declaration

In Javascript how does variable used before definitions?

console.log("b ", b);

var  b;

I want to understand how above statement work in javascript?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I would want to know how javascript run file  which have console.log("b ", b); var b;

Comment: in js, we use function and variable before declaration

Comment: Its not possible. Like in other programming languages you need to define your variables first. Check out @user2486 answer:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b` is `undefined` at code at Question. However, if `b` were a function, that variable declaration would be "hoisted" see ['Hoisted' JavaScript Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667199/hoisted-javascript-variables) and `b` would be defined within `console.log()` even where not actually defined until the next line.

```js
console.log("b ", b);

function b() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

JS first check how many variable and functions are going to use and variable are assigned as undefined and assigned at last.

So in the first example you can understand like `var b = undefined` and then `console.log("b ", b);` and then `b=1`;

```js
console.log("b ", b);
var b=1;
```

```js
console.log("b ", b);
```

```js
var b=1;
console.log("b ", b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use d and then initialize d it will print undefined.
but if you use d with out any initialization it will return b is not defined **Error** .

```js
console.log("d",d);
```

```js
   

 console.log("b "+b);
 var b = "What do you mean ?"    
 console.log("b ",b);
```